# Java Eclipse: Read the code of a class imported from a library

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I'm working in a project environment Eclipse Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2) in which I am using classes imported from some libraries. Currently I have to build a class diagram of the work done so far and to do that, I'm using the "ObjectAid Explorer Eclipse UML plugin" without problems. Unfortunately I can not create it anyway integrating relationships to classes imported and then I was planning to re-create them in a package so that you can create this class diagram. How can I read the code of a class imported from a jar library?
Thanks so much !

Comment: well you can use java decompiler to do the same. But if the library is opensource, you can download the sources and attach the sources.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to read just the method signatures, inside Eclipse from Project Explorer, navigate where the .jar is located and expand it; you will be able to view the classes and their methods.

If however you want to read the entire code of every class, you need the .jar that attaches the sources on it. Developers usually package a Java Project *without* the sources files and create separate JARs that contain them. Look for the a JAR named `<library_name>-src.jar`.